# Explain why does the program prints out 4 for both x and y?

Tags: python, swap

This is the code that I wrote, Also I Want to know why didn’t x and y swap numbers?

```
x = 3
y = 4
x = y
y = x
print (y)
print (x)
```

Output:

```
4
4
```

Comment: Youa assigned `x=y` (which sets x to 4), then `y=x` (which sets y to 4).  Why wouldn't it print what you got?  If you want to swap, use `x,y=y,x`.

Comment: no i just wanted to know why. i already know how to swap. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your code is essentially doing this:

```
x = 3
y = 4
x = y # y is 4
y = x # x is now 4 also
```

To swap the values stored in variables you usually have to have a "temporary" variable.

```
def swap(x, y):
    temp = x
    x = y
    y = temp
```

Comment: You don't have to use a temporary variable.  In Python, just `x,y=y,x`.

Comment: You don't need a temp variable. `x, y = y, x`

Comment: This guy is new, its actually a way I did with Javascript. However, they are correct, x, y = y, x. This is a parallel assignment. The ones that are going to be assigned in the variable will all be executed first, then stored into the corresponding variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is assigning x to y then assigning it back.

```py
x = 3 #x=3
y = 4 #y=4
x = y # x = y = 4 -> x=4
y = x # y = x = 4 -> y=4
```

If you want to swap vals, then just do this

```py
x = 3
y = 4
x,y = y,x
```

It also works with any number of vals

```py
x=3
y=4
z=5

#you can also assign like this
x,y,z = 3,4,5

x,y,z = y,z,x
#this makes x=4, y=5, z=3
```